# How do I pass a string variable that contains a parentheses “(“ to a script as a parameter?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that receives a string value (variable called “password”) as a parameter when it is run. This password parameter can contain any characters and is set to be a random value every 24 hours.

Today the password ended in an open parenthesis “(“ which gave me this error -
`An expression was expected after ‘(‘`

There are many parameters that are mandatory passed to the script. The parenthesis in the password parameter not getting escaped caused the script to not run.

How exactly do I get PowerShell to recognise the parenthesis as part of the string value?

Note: The script is run as part of  Jenkins job and the password value is passed to it from an external service.

Comment: You can likely fix this by quoting the string value(s) correctly. Show us the Jenkins job definition (or whatever templating component performs the string substitution/interpolation)

Comment: It sounds like you're actually trying to evaluate the password, which would be horribly bad and allow for injection. Reproduce the problem and then post information here on how you're dealing with the password where the parenthesis is giving you a problem.

Comment: It would be nice to see the exact line of code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].